# Input radio elements result always checked

Tags: javascript, html

I've searched all the web about it but i couldn't find a solution in javascript without jquery. The problem is the following: I have an entire array of radio elements, which should be checked or unchecked depending on database data. And this is accomplished. Now i have to make the radio button "uncheckable" to change the database data through the form.

I tried to make it in plain javascript as i don't want to think about frontend libraries for the moment.

The html is the following:

```
<td>
<input class="graphs" name="g4" value="S" defaultvalue="N" checked="true" type="radio">
</td>
<td>
<input class="graphs" name="g5" value="S" defaultvalue="N" type="radio">
```

The Javascript is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = (function(){
    return function(){
        var allRadios = document.getElementsByClassName('graphs');
        var x = 0;
        for(x = 0; x < allRadios.length; x++){

            allRadios[x].onclick = function() {
                if(this.checked == true){
                    this.checked = false;
                }else{
                    this.checked = true
                }
            };
        }
    }})();
    </script>
```

I've tried to debug and the result is always the same: the first if is executed and always true, even when the element is not checked.

I've tried the same script in jsfiddle and it works right. Is it a problem of my browser?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `this.checked = !this.checked`

Comment: Consider using a checkbox instead or add an extra empty option to the radio buttons. Users wont expect that you're able to uncheck a radio button

Comment: use checkbox instead of radio, you have different name for each radio button. it is better to use checkbox if you want to check/uncheck sme element and manipulate some data

Comment: Use a `change` event instead of `click` for radio buttons

Comment: i don't use a checkbox cause it doesn't have a defaultvalue attribute, which i need in order to save the content in the database.

Comment: @Pointy same semantic error, the radio button is uncheckabe but not checkable, the if always returns true

Comment: @softwareplay Radio buttons don't have a "defaultvalue" attribute either.

Answer (score 1):

`this.checked == true` in else block is not an assignment

Answer (score 1):

If you want a radio to be uncheckable the you can disable it statically, you don't need to use any javascript.

For Unckecked disabled

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="N" disabled>
```

Four Checked disabled

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="N" checked disabled>
```

Comment: Sorry for my english, i want the button to be checkable and uncheckable, this is acomplished just in javascript with radio buttons